# Entropy and information relation

Tags: computer-science, estimation, entropy

In terms of compression and information theory, the entropy of a source is the average amount of information (in bits) that symbols from the source can convey. Informally speaking, if we are certain about the outcome of an event then entropy is less.

```
J. Principe, D. Xu, and J. Fisher, “Information theoretic learning,” in Unsupervised Adaptive Filtering, S. Haykin, Ed. New York: Wiley, 2000, vol. I, pp. 265–319.
```

Entropy (Shannon and Renyis) has been used in learning by minimizing the entropy of the error as an objective function instead of the Mean Square error.

My questions are

1. What is the rationale for minimizing entropy of error? When entropy is maximum, what can we say about the information? 
   Thank you

Comment: No,this is not related to homework.I have come across entropy for parameter estimation in papers - 

    Deniz Erdogmus, Member, IEEE, and Jose C. Principe, An Error-Entropy Minimization Algorithm for Supervised Training of Nonlinear Adaptive Systems

    J. Principe, D. Xu, and J. Fisher, “Information theoretic learning,” in Unsupervised Adaptive Filtering, S. Haykin, Ed. New York: Wiley, 2000, vol. I, pp. 265–319.

Comment: The question is based on these paper,I will update my question and request to kindly remove the negative vote after the update is appropriate.

Comment: Don't know why you're getting down voted. This is a well researched question that is useful and clear.

Comment: @MrAlias: it's off-topic.

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks for the feedback! The [flag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) feature is intended to be use for this purpose however.

Comment: Really? I would never have guessed....

Comment: @RiaGeorge: i would start by trying to get at least some rough descriptions of that authors' "error" and their term "mutual information". minimizing entropy of a value is roughly just minimizing the value's difference from expectation, so from your description it sounds like they're minimizing the difference from an expected error, which is meaningless. there is a distinct possibility that you have misunderstood something, or that you have tripped into one of the currently too common pseudo-science things.

Comment: In this paper "ENTROPY MINIMIZATION FOR PARAMETER ESTIMATION PROBLEMS WITH
UNKNOWN DISTRIBUTION OF THE OUTPUT NOISE and http://papers.nips.cc/paper/1765-learning-informative-statistics-a-nonparametnic-approach.pdf the authors mention that entropy of error minimization is equivalent to maximizing likelihood.I just cannot follow these terms & will be grateful for explanation in simple words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a better fit at [CS Stack Overflow](http://cs.stackexchange.com), probably, but as long as we have a computer science tag I am unwilling to downvote it.  (Note:  **NOT** [CS Theory Stack Overflow](http://cst.stackexchange.com), that's for research grade discussions, which this is not.  They will downvote and close immediately.)

Anyway, the intuitive answer is almost exactly as you have said:  As you minimize the entropy of something, you are increasing your ability to predict it.  If you minimize the entropy of an error between model and results, you are saying that you are increasing the predictive power of the model.

To sharpen this intuition mathematically, go forth and study things like the Expectation Maximization algorithm until you have internalized it.  If you find EM hard-going, then go forth and study things like Bayesian Probability until EM makes sense.

Comment: Does entropy minimization = minimization of information or is it the reverse relation? By information do we mean information content or just information when we say that Shannons entropy is related to information. Can you please explain this part (Q1) effect of maximizing and minimizing entropy on information?Confused about whether its information,or mutual information or information content that is related with entropy.

Comment: I cannot reasonably explain these things in less space than it takes the original papers to do so, no.

Comment: Could you please atleast answer the doubt that increase of entropy = increase of information or not And if my this information we mean the information content or what kind of information are we talking about. Then I will follow your leads and study. But, these answers cannot be found directly in the context of entropy increase = information increase or decrease.

Comment: You seem to be operating under the assumption that entropy and information are the same things.  They're not.  Entropy is a measure of the _expected_ information (in the probabilistic sense) of a random process.  It is also a measure of the uncertainty-- note how those negative signs work!  So when you minimize entropy _of an error expression_ you are also minimizing the _uncertainty_ of the error.  And after all, if there is no uncertainty in the error, then you obviously know what it is and can account for it.